# Changing read permissions on /private/etc recursively

Tags: macos, permission, sudo

I was trying to make my /private/etc folder and all its contents world-readable. 'Permission denied' messages from a number of internal files and folders were a recurrent theme whenever I did a find operation on that folder. But `chmod -R` seems to have failed here. Can someone please explain why I get this error message and what I should do to fix it? I'm on OS X 10.8.3.

```
$ sudo chmod -R a+r /private/etc
sudo: /private/etc/sudoers is mode 0444, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

In fact any read operation in the directory seems to fail:

```
$sudo stat /private/etc/raddb/sql/sqlite 
sudo: /private/etc/sudoers is mode 0444, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to rethink changing the permissions of everything under `/private/etc` to be world readable. This poses a serious security risk (as seen from the way `sudo` locks you out when you make `/private/etc/sudoers` world readable) to your machine. Maybe there's another Ask Different question here that'll help you solve a problem you think you're solving by making these unsafe changes?

Comment: Thanks Ian. Honestly, I hadn't thought it through. Your pointers are very helpful though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the permissions on `/private/etc/sudoers` is definitely a no-no. The `sudo` command will fail to work if that file's permissions are not `0440` as you are noticing. This is a security measure -- the command distrusts any permission setting that is less restrictive than `0440` as it allows for potential tampering with sudo permissions on the box.

Normally you'd [boot in to single user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) to fix this problem. This lets you log in with elevated privledges so you can do a:

```
chmod 440 /private/etc/sudoers
```

and get your `sudo` command back.

But I found [this article](http://astrails.com/blog/2009/9/29/how-to-fix-a-hosed-etc-sudoers-file-on-mac-osx) that had an alternative that doesn't require a reboot and works if your account has Administrator level access. I haven't tried it, but it seems sound.

Open a Finder window a hit `Shift-Command-G` to get the "Go To" dialog. Enter `/private/etc` in the dialog and hit the `Go` button.

Find the `sudoers` file in the Finder window, select it and press `Command-I` to open the information window for the file and change the permissions on the file so they match:

[image: Permissions for your sudoers file]

Close the information window and you should be back in business.

All this being said: I would strongly encourage you to rethink changing the permissions of everything under `/private/etc` to be world readable. This poses a serious security risk (as seen from the way `sudo` locks you out when you make `/private/etc/sudoers` world readable) to your machine. Maybe there's another Ask Different question here that'll help you solve a problem you think you're solving by making these unsafe changes?

Comment: This is very comprehensive and I really appreciate it. I'd have voted up this answer, but I'm two points short of acquiring that privilege. :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "change the permissions on the file so they match (the image)"? I mean, I see two admin users (my admin account and another admin user) with "Read only" privilege and "everyone" with "No Access". I don't see "system" or "wheel" and they're not in the Users & Groups or any other list when I click on the plus button